# Create a PDF on server-side with some data and then create a download link for the user

Tags: php, pdf

i want using php generate a pdf in my site with some format and some values i have into some vars, any suggestion of a good script and good practices to know about? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ajax call to your php and then push the generated PDF to the browser.

you can create PDF server side with [this](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en).

Answer (score 1):

Using a HTML to PDF generator is probably the best way.  The one I have found the easiest to use, and use regularly, is http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm

It can be daunting at first, but once you get used to it it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Have a look at the [examples](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples), and see how easy it is to create PDFs with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

if you have shell access, you can use http://www.pd4ml.com/ for converting html to pdf. its really easy, but its not free and you need shell access.